# How to derive non-degenerate Bose-Einstein statistics in the canonical ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-statistics

The derivation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics#Derivation_in_the_canonical_approach) assumes high degeneracy:

> Let $w(n,g)$ be the number of ways of distributing $n$ particles among the $g$ sublevels of an energy level.
>
> (...)
>
> The number of ways that a set of occupation numbers $n_i$ can be realized is the product of the ways that each individual energy level can be populated:
>
> $$W=\prod_i w(n_i,g_i)=\prod_i{\frac{(n_i+g_i-1)!}{n_i!(g_i-1)!}}\approx \prod_i{\frac {(n_i+g_i)!}{n_i!(g_i-1)!}}$$
>
> where the approximation assumes that $n_i\gg 1$.

I think the "$n_i\gg 1$" is a typo and they actually meant $g_i\gg 1$. If $g_i = 1$, for example, then $W = 1$.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: @heather How to derive non-degenerate Bose-Einstein statistics in the canonical ensemble?

Comment: @heather if you have any link it would work too, though I'd prefer a proof following the approach given in that Wikipedia article (for the case g=1).

Comment: The best way to derive B-E statistics in canonical ensemble is to say that one is approximately in grand canonical ensemble, since B-E statistics are exactly derivable in that case.

Comment: Note that the cited derivation from wikipedia is in fact performed in the microcanonical ensemble (N and E fixed, we maximize the entropy). In the canonical ensemble you should calculate the partition function for average energy <E> and N fixed.

Comment: In the Grand Canonical Partition function, replace $\mu\beta$ by $i\omega$, multiply by $\exp(-i\omega N)$,  then integrate over $\omega$ from minus infinity to plus infinity and divide by $2\pi$.

Comment: @Wood, You can see *Reif, F. (1965). Fundamentals of Statistical and Thermal Physics. McGraw–Hill. ISBN 978-0-07-051800-1, p.342*. Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340850/how-to-obtain-the-bose-einstein-distribution-from-the-canonical-ensemble/341303#341303

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that Bose-Einstein statistics only arises from the [*grand canonical ensemble*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_canonical_ensemble), i.e. for a system where the energy and the number of particles are not fixed ; only their *mean* energy $\langle E \rangle $ and *mean* number of particles $\langle N \rangle $ are fixed respectively by the temperature $T$ and the chemical potential $\mu$ of the thermostat.

However, one can show that, at the [thermodynamic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit), at thermodynamic equilibrium, all statistical ensembles are equivalent since the relative particle number fluctuations $\Delta N$ drop to zero as $N\rightarrow +\infty$.

So what you are trying to do here is to derive the Bose-Einstein statistics in the canonical ensemble, which is only possible *in the thermodynamic limit*. This is the reason of the approximation "$n_i\gg 1$", which actually stands for "*at the thermodynamic limit*".

> **EDIT : How to perform properly the approximation**

As stated in [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_statistics#Derivation_in_the_canonical_approach), we have :
$$
W=\prod_i\frac{(n_i+g_i-1)!}{n_i!(g_i-1)!}
$$
In the case $\forall\,i,\;g_i=1$, we have :
$$
W=\prod_i\frac{n_i!}{n_i!0!}=1
$$
with the convention $0!=1$.

This obviously stays true in the limit $n_i\gg 1$. You always have to take the limit $n_i\gg 1$ *at the end of all calculations*, i.e. *after* taking $g_i=1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If $g_i = 1$, then $W = 1$, but the "approximation" gives a huge number! And it only gets worse for high values of $n_i$.

Comment: "but the "approximation" gives a huge number" $\rightarrow$ could you explain a bit more what you mean by this? I'm not sure to understand your problem...

Comment: It becomes $W \approx \prod_i n_i+1 $, which is completely wrong and even worse for $n_i \gg 1$. Also it makes no sense to maximize $W$ if it's a constant function.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has 2 votes, it's just wrong. It makes no sense to maximize a function $W=1$.

Comment: From the article: "(...) we wish to find the set of $n_i$ for which $W$ is maximised". You just typed a few facts about Bose-Einstein statistics without addressing the question.