# Trying to derive Bose-Einstein Condensation using the canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

My approach:

1. Write down the partition function $Z_1$ of a single particle,
   approximate the summation with integral so $Z_1 = \int e^{-\beta E} g(E) dE$ where $g(E)$ is the density of states.
2. Mark the ground state with a dummy variable $\mu$ so $Z_1'=Z_1-1+\mu$.
3. The partition function $Z$ of $N$ bosons is $\frac{1}{N!}Z_1^{'N}$.
4. The number of particles in the ground state is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\log Z\big |_{\mu=1}$.

However, my result is quite different from BEC, specifically, the ratio of particles in the ground state is independent of the particle number $N$.

I suspect this derivation must contain some logical mistakes but I am unable to find them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think this is an already answered question:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340850/how-to-obtain-the-bose-einstein-distribution-from-the-canonical-ensemble?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that the partition function of N bosons can not be written as the multiplication of N partition functions of a single boson because they are indistinguishable.

Comment: Yes, you are right; the partition function is, in general, more complicated. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/703139/derivation-of-partition-function-for-n-identical-quantum-harmonic-oscillators) for the case of a harmonic oscillator potential.